# 5 letter arrrangments of Mississippi

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements are possible with five letters chosen from Mississippi? How would I approach this problem? I just want some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: first forget the repetitions, and then account for them at the end.

Comment: That would be (11C5)?

Comment: Note that the order of each arrangement counts.

Comment: Then that would be 11P5?

Comment: Yes, before taking into account the repetitions.

Comment: Then to account for the repetitions, I would consider the repetitions of each letter right? For example, the sequences with repetitions of s would be p(5; 4, 1). After doing it all for each letter I would find the sum and subtract that from 11p5, right?