# How many 4 letters words can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics

How many different $4$ letter words can be formed by using "MISSISSIPPI".

my answer to this will be $\binom{11}{4}=330$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Can you explain, why do you think that $C_4^{11}$ is the right answer?

Comment: What you mean "by using <another word>"? do you mean different factors of length $4$ in the other word?

Comment: I mean that by using "MISSISSIPPI" can form how many different kind of 4 letter words.

Comment: Can you repeat letters?

Comment: ya repetition is allow, trying to grasp the concept, don't know the formula is used in the right scenario.

Comment: To clarify:  is $MMMM$ a possible word on your list?  Presumably $SSSS$ is possible (as there are four $S's$ to choose from).  But there is only the one $M$ so I'd have assumed that you couldn't make $MMMM$.

Comment: Recommend breaking into cases.  How many words can be made if all letters are distinct?  How many words can be made if exactly one letter occurs twice (e.g. *miss*)?  if exactly one letter occurs thrice (e.g. *siss*)?  if two letters are repeated (e.g. *piip*)?  if a letter occurs four times (e.g. *ssss*).  The number $\binom{11}{4}$ unfortunately is incorrect for this situation.  Remember that order of letters within words matters and that not all of your eleven letters are distinct.

Comment: An answer of $\binom{11}{4}$ would count the number of subsets (*where order doesn't matter*) of letters from an eleven letter word where all eleven letters are different.  An answer of $\binom{11}{4}4!$ would count the number of four letter words made from letters from an eleven letter word where all eleven letters are different.  Consider the question of "*how many four letter words can you make from the word AAAAAAAAAAA?*"  By your logic, the answer would still have been $\binom{11}{4}$, but there is clearly only one possible: AAAA.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20238/6-letter-permutations-in-mississippi and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517101/5-letter-arrrangments-of-mississippi The first one covers a technique which will work for any length of word.

Comment: Number of words of length $n$ is given by: ${1, 4, 15, 53, 176, 550, 1610, 4340, 10430, 21420, 34650, 34650}$

Answer (score 3):

To clarify:  I am assuming that this works like Scrabble.  That is, you have exactly those $11$ letters from which to choose.  Thus, in particular,  $MMMM$ would not be allowed. If, to the contrary, you can reuse letters then the answer is trivially $4^4$.

I think the easiest way to count these is to track the $M's$ and $P's$.  After all, these are the only constrained ones (as both $SSSS$ and $IIII$ are possible). Accordingly, let $(m,p)$ denote the case in which exactly $m$ $M's$ and $p$ $P's$ appear.  Of course $m\in \{0,1\}$ and $p\in \{0,1,2\}$.  We remark that once the $M's$ and $P's$ are settled, you can choose between $S,I$ freely for the other slots.  We work the six cases separately.

$(0,0)$.  We have four slots to fill however we like with $S,I$ so $2^4=\fbox {16}$

$(1,0)$.   We have four ways to place the $M$ and then three free slots so $4\times 2^3=\fbox {32}$

$(0,1)$.   As in the case $(0,1)$ we get $\fbox {32}$

$(0,2)$.   we have $\binom 42 = 6$ ways to place the $P's$ and then two free slots so $6\times 2^2=\fbox {24}$

$(1,1)$.  Four ways to place the $M$, then three ways to place the $P$, and then two free slots so $4\times 3\times 2^2=\fbox {48}$

$(1,2)$.   Four ways to place the $M$ then three ways to place the two $P's$ and then one free slot so $4\times 3\times 2=\fbox {24}$

FInally we get $$16+32+32+24+48+24=\fbox {176}$$

Note:  while I wouldn't say the preceding calculation was difficult it is certainly error prone so I advise checking it carefully.

Comment: Yes, but as I asked in the comments above, my guess is that the OP was talking about repeating the $S's$ and $I's$.  That is, I do not believe that $MMMM$ is allowed.  Of course the OP should clarify.  If things like $MMMM$ are allowed then the count is trivially $4^4$,

Comment: I got $167$ (though mine solution is also prone to error from the same reason that you've mentioned).

Comment: I note that you don't have $IIII$ for example.

Comment: 176 is the right answer.

Comment: @IanMiller  Thanks.  I just worked it with the generating function...I assume that's how you did it?

Comment: Yeh, I used the generating function. I wrote some Mathematica code a while back where I can enter any word and it calculates the generating function and pulls out all the coefficients so this was a very easy one to check.

Comment: Actually even if repetition is allowed $4^4$ will not be the answer, because the formula takes repeated letter words as different. The formula sees $ MMSI$ as two words instead of one(as M repeats)

Comment: @N.S.JOHN  Not following.  What formula?  To me "with repetition" just means that each slot can have $M,S,I,P$ with no restrictions.  Hence $4^4$.

Comment: $4^4$ is only true if we see $MMSI$ and its kind as twodifferent words instead of one.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN  Still not following.  $MMSI$ is clearly just one word.  With repetition there are $4$ choices for the first slot, $4$ for the second slot, and so on.  Hence $4\times 4\times 4 \times 4 = 4^4$.

Comment: Yes you are right I made a mistake thanks.